# Favorite questions and answers from the 3rd quarter of 2019

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

Another quarter ended in the year. We are back with favorite questions and answers.

Following the tradition, we would ask the community to link your favorite questions and answers created from **1<sup>st</sup> July to September 30**.

You can search all eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2019-07..2019-09) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2019-07..2019-09) posted in the past quarter. Since, we received 516 questions and 837 answers, here are some data queries to make the decision process easier.

- [Questions with the most number of votes from the third quarter of 2019](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/07/01)
- [Questions with the most number of views from the third quarter of 2019](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/07/01)
- [Answers with most number of votes from the third quarter of 2019](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/07/01)

The above questions and answers are only for your hint. Feel free to mention any question or answer you enjoyed reading. Since **this is not a competition**, there's no need to mention one question or answer per one answer. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself which you think didn't get the appreciation they deserved.

Answer (score 3):

I particularly appreciated [this question about the "Landshut" references in 2018's *Suspiria*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/102355/49), since it made me sensible for looking out to aspects in the film that I might have otherwise not have spent that much thought on when watching it. In general, the film had a lot more political background aspects fit into the narrative than the giallo original and the question was a perfect catalyst for discussing these.

In a similar vein would be [my answer on the motivation of the protagonist from *Money Monster*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/101956/49). The question itself was already interesting when just considering the protagonist's character alone, but it again opened the opportunity for discussing the film's general approach to the financial crisis, which I was glad grasping.

And in general this figures into a bigger point that emphasizes **where this site really shines, namely what our documentation calls *"adding to the appreciation of the work"***. It is when questions lead to insights about the film that you might very well notice but maybe not spend a whole lot of consideration onto if there wasn't a question prompting you to look further into it.

In fact I originally wasn't sure about listing only stuff I contributed to, but afterall this is part of what personally moves me about the site. It emphasizes the opportunity for personal pleasure this site offers, not only by reading interesting questions and answers but also by inspiring you to think about aspects in films you watch and maybe even putting these into words, be it in an engaging question or a new interesting answer to an old question. It is ultimately not about collecting a ton of reputation points, but having a venue to discuss and share your thoughts on films you liked (or didn't like). And I deliberately keep saying *discuss* here albeit knowing that this isn't a "discussion forum". It's this formalized and structured way for discussion that the Q&A format enables so well.